# Comment immediate after closing DIVs in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I remember IE will have some problems in layout when a comment is placed immediate after closing DIVs

E.g.

```
<div id='header'>



</div><!--/header-->
```

I forgot which version of IE will be affected, anyone can point me to the right direction for this bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It affects IE6 and is fixed in IE7, accoring to [Position Is Everything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html).

(It's comments between floated elements that trigger the bug.)